# ML training process is not on GPU

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, tensorflow

I just moved from AWS to Google Cloud Platform because of its lower GPU price. I followed the instructions on the website creating a compute engine instance with a K80 GPU, installed the latest-versioned Tensorflow, keras, cuda driver and cnDNN, everything goes very well. However when I try to train my model, the training process is still on CPU.

```
NVIDIA-SMI 387.26                 Driver Version: 387.26        
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.1, V9.1.85
Tensorflow version -1.4.1
cudnn cudnn-9.1-linux-x64-v7
Ubuntu 16.04
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you installed the cpu version of tensorflow?

Now, Google Cloud's compute engine has a VM OS image with all the needed software installed for an easier/faster way to get started: https://cloud.google.com/deep-learning-vm/